# Why does my code (linked with CUDA) occasionally cause a segmentation fault in Python?

Tags: python, cuda

I am creating a GPU accelerated convolution routine for python, which is back-ended to C which makes use of Cuda to access the GPU. To do this, have the following C code:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>


/* 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
GPU device functions for GPU modules 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
*/
__global__ void d_VectorConvolve(float *a, float *b, float *c, size_t n_a, size_t n_b, size_t half)
{
    size_t idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    float val = 0.0;

    if (idx < n_a)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n_b; j++)
        {
            int check = idx - half + j; // this is needed to ensure we dont attempt to index
                        // a value outsize the size of a.
            if (check > 0 && check < n_a)
            {
                val = val + a[idx - half + j]*b[j];
            }   
        }
        c[idx] = val;
    }
}
extern "C" {
void VectorConvolve(float *a, float *b, float *c, size_t n_a, size_t n_b, size_t half)
{
    float *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;

    cudaMalloc( &d_a, n_a*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc( &d_b, n_b*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc( &d_c, n_a*sizeof(float));

    cudaMemcpy( d_a, a, n_a*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy( d_b, b, n_b*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy( d_c, c, n_a*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    d_VectorConvolve <<< ceil(n_a / 256.0), 256 >>> (d_a, d_b, d_c, n_a, n_b, half);

    cudaMemcpy( c, d_c, n_a*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    cudaFree(d_c);
}
}
```

This file is saved vector_functions.cu, which I compile with nvcc to produce a .so :

```
nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC -shared -o vector_functions.so vector_functions.cu
```

This all works fine, and the code works in C. I create an **init**.py file which uses the .so file created:

```
def get_vector_functions():
    dll = ctypes.CDLL(current_dir + '/vector_functions.so', mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)

    # convolve funtion
    vector_convolve = dll.VectorConvolve
    vector_convolve.argtypes = [POINTER(c_float), POINTER(c_float), POINTER(c_float), c_size_t, c_size_t, c_size_t]

    return vector_convolve

# create __cuda_sum function with get_cuda_sum()
__vector_convolve = get_vector_functions()

def cuda_convolve(a,b):
    a = a.astype('float32')
    b = b.astype('float32')

    a_shape = a.shape[0]
    b_shape = b.shape[0]

    half = int(b_shape/2.)

    a_p = a.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float))
    b_p = b.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float))
    c_p = np.zeros(a_shape).ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float))

    __vector_convolve(a_p, b_p, c_p, a_shape, b_shape,  half)
    c = make_nd_array(c_p, [a_shape], dtype=np.float32, order='C', own_data=True)
    return c
```

Now this works fine, and I can load my module to do large convolutions fast. The problem is, occasionally, I get an segmentation fault and I have no idea why. Once I get this, I can't use this module again until I restart my computer.

I assume I am not managing my memory correctly? But it's strange how sometimes it works fine, and then all of a sudden, fails. I also feel that linking against an .so file may be a bad idea and may have something to do with it, but it was a quick solution to link python to C.

I am relatively experienced in python and getting into C. Most of the code I have here is adapted from online tutorials and other peoples code. I welcome all suggestions for why this may be, and what can be done to avoid this issue.

---

### EDIT 31/10/2017

The problem seems to go away if I run a few warm-up commands with the python interpreter:

```
cuda_convolve(np.ones(2**5), np.ones(100))
cuda_convolve(np.ones(2**10), np.ones(100))
cuda_convolve(np.ones(2**15), np.ones(100))
cuda_convolve(np.ones(2**18), np.ones(100))
```

After this, I can use it with large arrays with absolutely no issue. However if I load in the module without doing this "warm-up", I get a seg fault.

Comment: CUDA device code will never cause a host segfault. I would guess the device to host transfer is the source of the problem because that is the only code which writes to host memory, but that is just a guess

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually a solution to your segfault problem, but a way to finding the actual culprit behind the segfault.

There's no error checking in your code. How do you expect to find the error?

Use the following function to wrap all your CUDA calls:

```
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}
```

Now to modify your code:

```
extern "C" {
void VectorConvolve(float *a, float *b, float *c, size_t n_a, size_t n_b, size_t half)
{
    float *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;

    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc( &d_a, n_a*sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc( &d_b, n_b*sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc( &d_c, n_a*sizeof(float)));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy( d_a, a, n_a*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy( d_b, b, n_b*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy( d_c, c, n_a*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    d_VectorConvolve <<< ceil(n_a / 256.0), 256 >>> (d_a, d_b, d_c, n_a, n_b, half);

    // check if cuda kernel executed correctly
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError())
    // make sure kernel execution has ended
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize())

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy( c, d_c, n_a*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(d_a));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(d_b));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(d_c));
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Zindarod,

I have made these changes (which are incredibly useful). When I get the error now, it says:
<code>
    GPUassert: invalid argument vector_functions.cu 192
<code>
which corresponds to the following line:
'code'
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc( &d_a, n_a*sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc( &d_b, n_b*sizeof(float))); <-- line 192
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc( &d_c, n_a*sizeof(float)));

This only happened with a large input array (a has 2**16 values and b had 52).

Comment: I apologise for the formatting, I ran out of time editing it- hopefully you get the gist. I assume there is a problem allocating memory for some reason - I'm not sure why.

Comment: Thanks for your answer earlier. I've done some debugging and nothing seems to be wrong with the C code - it runs fine if compiled and ran in C. The problem seems to be with the interaction with the .so file (I think). If I run a "warm-up" with the GPU function increasing the data size, it works fine. :

cuda_convolve(np.ones(2**5), np.ones(100))

cuda_convolve(np.ones(2**10), np.ones(100))

cuda_convolve(np.ones(2**15), np.ones(100))

cuda_convolve(np.ones(2**18), np.ones(100))

Then I can work with large arrays. But if I don't do this before inputting a large array I get a seg fault